# How to remove prefixes into files using the Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, file-rename, batch-rename

My files are 
x_name.png, x_something.png, x_somethingElse.png

How can I remove the "x_" prefix from all these files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with a single line, you'll need a basic batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (x_*.*) do (
    set fname=%%a
    set fname=!fname:~2!
    ren "%%a" "!fname!"
)
```